# (HDFS) How to copy large data safely within a cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I've got to make big sample data(say 1TB) and have approximately 20GB text files.

so I tried to just copy that 50times to make it that bigger, but every time I tried hadoop fs -cp command, some of my datanode die.

I heard that in UNIX , when deleting large data one can use SHRINK to safely remove data from disk. is there somthing like that in hadoop to copy large data?

In short, is there any way to copy large data safely within a hadoop cluster?

or do I have to modify some configuration files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **distcp**. It runs MR job under the hood for copying data allowing us to leverage the parallelism provided by Hadoop.

Comment: Is distcp also possible within a cluster? I thought it is for migrating from one cluster to another, isn't it?

Comment: AFAIK, it is for both inter and intra-cluster copying. So, it should work.